# SEO issue and remove a trailing slash from URL

Tags: seo

We have a web site written in ASP.NET. When you open the following page:

http://concert.local/elki/

You can see the slash "/" at the end. We need to remove it in order to have:

http://concert.local/elki

I've tried some things to make it work, but it doesn't help. For example, when I add the following code in Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("http://concert.local/elki/"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://concert.local/elki/", "http://concert.local/elki"));
    }
}
```

The following error comes up:

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

There is also the following code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHead">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://concert.local/elki" />
</asp:Content>
```

That puts canonical stuff in page header.

How can I get the following URL:

http://concert.local/elki

?

Comment: Why do you need this?  They are the same address.  Your web server may be adding the additional slash.

Comment: We need this because my company pays some other people to do SEO and those people ask us to remove that slash?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer:  [url trailing slash and seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435336/url-trailing-slash-and-seo)

It basically says that Google prefers the trailing slash.  Just code consistently and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. The article you pointed me is really helpful, but we can't use URL with trailing slash. It has to be without it.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried to set up IIS 7 <rewrite> section as suggested, but the trailing slash is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official answer from Google. Effectively, they dont care whether you have a trailing slash or not
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

> Google treats each URL above separately (and equally) regardless of
>   whether it’s a file or a directory, or it contains a trailing slash or
>   it doesn’t contain a trailing slash.